# get parameter from form

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

In phonegap, I uses one jquery mobile framework. And I want to pass the form data to next page which is a div by using page url. I tries to use GetElementByID to retrieve the parameter `searchlocation`. It can't work probably. The parameter can't be retrieved and it do not go to next page. How can I solve it?

Down below is the function that change to next page DIV is the code of my phonegap:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#home').live('pagecreate',function(event) { 
$("#form").submit( function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var x=document.getElementById("searchlocation");
        $.mobile.changePage("#page1?param1="+x);
    });
});
</script>
```

And the form html:

```
<form id="form" method="POST" action="page1" data-ajax="false">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="search">
                    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                        <label for="search">
                            Search
                        </label>
                        <input name="searchword" id="searchword" placeholder="" value="" type="search" />
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="searchcondition">
                    <label for="searchmethod">
                    </label>
                    <select id="searchmethod" name="searchmethod" data-theme="e">
                        <option value="keyword">
                            Keyword
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain2" id="searchcondition2">
                    <label for="searchlocation2">
                    </label>
                    <select id="searchlocation" name="searchlocation"  data-theme="e">
                        <option value="Entire Collection">
                            Entire Collection
                        </option>
                        <option value="Pearl River Delta and Yangtze River Delta Collection">
                            Pearl River Delta and Yangtze River Delta Collection
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var x = document.getElementById("searchlocation");
```

The above code gets the element, not the value.

Considering you're using jQuery you can just use:

```
var x = $('#searchlocation').val();
```